# docker centosコンテナでのjenkins文字化け

Tags: centos, docker, jenkins, 文字化け

DockerコンテナでCI/CD環境の構築をしています。
[jenkins](https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins)から[centos7](https://hub.docker.com/_/centos/)を元にしたslave環境でシェル実行しています。

実行結果を確認すると日本語の部分が文字化けします。
docker公式イメージのcentos7にはja_JP.UTF8が入っていないようなのでcentosコンテナを起動し、コンテナ内で`localedef -f UTF-8 -i ja_JP ja_JP.UTF-8`を実行しました。

jenkins側では「jenkinsの管理>ノードの管理>設定」から、対象ノードの「環境変数」に`LANG=ja_JP.UTF8`を設定しています。
しかし、日本語箇所の文字化けが解消されません。
文字化け解消のためにどのような設定を行えばよいのでしょうか？

お力添えいただけると幸いです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 下記のサイトを参考にして自己解決しました。
https://knjname.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/02/27/012957

jenkinsの管理>ノードの管理>ノード設定から「高度な設定」を開くと設定箇所が出現します。

Answer (score 1):

下記のサイトを参考にして自己解決しました。

[JenkinsのSSHスレーブが文字化けする場合](https://knjname.hateblo.jp/entry/2015/02/27/012957)

jenkinsの管理>ノードの管理>ノード設定から「高度な設定」を開くと設定箇所が表示されます。

---

*この投稿は @teachi15 さんのコメント の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*